# How to reset custom Performance Counter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, performancecounter

I have created a custom performance counter using the following code:

```
public class PerfCounter
{
    private PerformanceCounter perfCounter;

    PerfCounter(string CategoryName, string CounterName)
    {
        perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter(CategoryName, CounterName, false);
        perfCounter.BeginInit();
    }

    public void IncrementBy(long value)
    {
        perfCounter.IncrementBy(value);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        //what should I add here?
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but I don't know how to Reset the counter. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Perhaps this will help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195851/reset-performance-counter-from-command-line

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do this:

```
public void Reset()
{
    perfCounter.RawValue = 0;
}
```